# AFNetworking request log

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-chrome-extension, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

`Chrome` gives a granular breakdown of the request lifecycle for a single resource.
The lifecycle shows how much time is spent in the following categories:

- **Queuing**
- **Stalled**
- **Request sent**
- **Waiting** (Time to first byte (TTFB))
- **Content Download**

I was wondering does `AFNetworking` give us the ability to captures these categories? 
I tried digging but there's not much info about these.
*Although I have calculated the complete `duration` of request hit to response got time,* but how could we make use of such granular breakdown through `AFNetworking` in order to improve our app performance.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger

Comment: Thanks @suhit, I've checked that out but it won't give aforementioned categories.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with `Instruments`?